# AutoLoginFilter: Current URL Generates Exception

Tags: liferay

I have Liferay installed on two different servers, both using the same LDAP configuration/server.

My first environment queries the LDAP server and auto-logins the user. My second environment does not and throws this exception:

```
07:57:46,519 ERROR [ajp-bio-20120-exec-10][AutoLoginFilter:257] Current URL 
/myPortal/home generates exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

They of course have different virtual hosts; any idea as to what is causing this?

Additional info:

- `live.users.enabled=true`
- `users.reminder.queries.enabled=false`
- The only difference between the two environments is a change in the
  URL - which tells me somewhere this second URL maybe needs to be set

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an "***@***" in my import filter. Slightly embarrassing.