# AutoLoginFilter: Current URL /health/index.html Generates Exception

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.4

This message fills the logs and makes anything else difficult to see.

**ERROR [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-76][AutoLoginFilter:256] Current URL /health/index.html generates exception: null**

I don't know what is this error. I got this error log from unknown source that's why not able to tell the proper details.

But If anyone had faced the same problem or knows about it then please help me find a solution to it.

Found a similar question maybe that could help:- [AutoLoginFilter: Current URL Generates Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890234/autologinfilter-current-url-generates-exception)